# Убрать кавычки у строки чтобы массив был явно определен (php)

Tags: php

Есть переменная, которая приходит извне в формате "['var1', 'var2']"
php определяет её как строку, оно и ясно

есть ли возможность через php вытащить массив ['var1', 'var2'] сохранив все внутренности без изменений?

Comment: json_decode. Правда вам придётся заменить одинарные кавычки на двойные

Comment: json_decode возвращает NULL, почему -  не понимаю, тоже пробовал
, Кавычки везде двойные

Comment: спасибо за ответ, как всегда как только вопрос задашь мысли в голову лезть начинают

вместо кавычек были &quot;, хотя отладчик интерпретировал как ", сделал замену &quot; -> " и все ок, json_decode отработал